# std::vector _M_start and _M_finish are the same

Tags: c++, vector, gdb, stdvector

I'm debugging a `std::vector` in GDB and I can't tell what the vector believes its current size to be. The vector is declared as `std::vector<custom_struct_t *> myVec;`.

```
(gdb) p myVec.size()
Cannot evaluate function -- may be inlined
```

Examining the vector:

```
(gdb) p myVec
[...]
    _M_impl = {
      [...]
      _M_start = 0x8052a0500, 
      _M_finish = 0x8052a0500, 
      _M_end_of_storage = 0x8052a0600
    }
  }, <No data fields>}
```

Here I see that `_M_start` and `_M_finish` are the same value. Is this indicative of a *zero-length* vector or a *one-length* vector?

Comment: When I try `p myVec`: it shows something like.`std::vector of length 0, capacity 0`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For libstdc++ (gcc) implementation, this indicates 0-sized vector, as evidenced by `std::vector::size()` function:

```
size_type
size() const _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
{ return size_type(this->_M_impl._M_finish - this->_M_impl._M_start); }
```

This source code can be found, for example, in [GCC online documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.1.0/libstdc++/api/a00599_source.html).